# Is a standard AC/DC USB power supply galvanically isolated?

Tags: usb, ac, isolation

I've definitely seen some sketchy, super low-cost DC devices which plug into the wall and have no galvanic isolation (think $5 WiFi-enabled smart plugs from Target,) but those devices don't have wires coming out and weren't intended to plug into anything else.

Realizing that assuming leads to unsafe conditions, is it safe to assume that the standard USB charger is galvanically isolated? Is it a fair guess that any bin of random chargers from reputable sources, e.g. mainline phone manufacturers, will be galvanically isolated?

If so, is this because of electrical codes or because of intelligent SMPS design?

Comment: Yes, it's a fair guess. Lack of galvanic isolation could result in death and would fail any electrical safety certification.

Comment: Can you spot [two concentric squares](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes#Class_II) somewhere on the case?

Comment: @greybeard that's really fantastic! I had no idea I could look for that logo. Does it necessarily follow, though, that the device is galvanically isolated? According to that article, seems like the same could be accomplished through appropriate insulation. Or is the argument that since no one knows what could be downstream of the USB cable, the only way to be sure it is Class-II is to galvanically isolate at the source?

Comment: They're virtually always isolated, even the $1 eBay units that catch fire if you use them too long.

Comment: *Does the double insulation logo/class II imply galvanic isolation?* I wish, but in Europe, that would be class III - logo: a diamond with a Roman III inside. I'd bet my health on each and every one I touch being galvanically isolated. I think the distances for class III/SELV/PELV aren't necessarily met.

Answer (score 2):

Electrical codes require the products to be safe.

So yes, a standard USB power supply is expected to have galvanically isolated output.

Some leakage current is allowed and sometimes there is an Y capacitor between the mains input and isolated output for electromagnetic interferenve reduction. Usually the leakage is so low that it does not matter.

So they must have isolation or a lot of people would be dead by now, touching their phones or USB connectors while charging their phones.

The problem is that the insulation may fail over time during use if there is poor design or manufacturing error.

The cheaper the product, the less quality and effort has been put into manufacturing the components required for safety.

But just as well an expensive quality brand product may develop a fault, and people have died from them too. It is just much less likely.

Comment: Youtube user "bigclivedotcom" showed a tear-down of a very cheap USB charger which had only a 0.25mm (**zero point two five millimetres**) gap between a live mains trace and a USB output trace. So yeah, you get what you pay for... some vendors simply care about profits more than your life. Don't buy those chargers. Properly made chargers are safe.